# How should we navigate workplace conflict due to political differences?

Tags: conflict-resolution

How should we navigate workplace conflict due to political differences?  I would appreciate any help on this topic.

Comment: What is the conflict?  Does it resolve itself by simply not discussing politics at work?

Comment: "I prefer not to discuss religion or politics at work.". Just say that on all appropriate occasions.

Comment: 'I don't mess with religion, politics, or other mens wives'

Comment: This is very vague and I would have put on hold as either too broad or unclear, but I think the linked question probably addresses your concerns.  If not, please [edit] in more details.

Answer (score 5):

Most employers, managers and supervisors would rather you not discuss politics, religion and sex at work. They don't particularly care to have their offices being turned into a war zone with employees turning on each other for reasons that have nothing to do with the business of the employer.

Not discussing politics, religion and sex in the office is just about the safest way to prevent disputes about politics, religion and sex from escalating in the office.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally management will ask people not to discuss politics etc. But if they don't, even after you ask them to, there's still options. FWIW I have been working through this list in our office because we have the problem too.

1. Ask the coworker(s) not to discuss the topic(s) when you're around
2. If they persist, remind them that you would rather they did not.
3. Leave the work area. This may not be an option for you, but I have begun walking into my boss's office and saying "X is talking about politics again, what's happening with you". I think he gets my point that I'm not getting anything done at my desk. Or you could just have a cup of tea, a walk outside, or whatever. Alcohol may also help, if that's allowed.
4. Leave the workplace. If you have flexitime, this may be a good time to use it.
5. Look for other employment. Transfer within the company, or just plain find another job. Despite what some people say, it's perfectly legitimate to change jobs because of an unpleasant work environment. Idiots discussing their unpleasant politics counts.

I suggest not getting involved, even if it is very tempting. You're likely to inflame the situation rather than calm it. Your goal is, after all, to stop politics being discussed.

Comment: Upvoted, don't know  why would it be voted down. It's a good advice, no matter if you have burning political passion within, there's time to work and time to play and discuss out of work stuff. There's a reason why some workplaces will have "no football casual stuff" on Casual Fridays. To avoid conflict and unnecessary friction. Even if nobody bats an eyelid at such conversations, I'd always, *always* err on the side of caution when it comes to personal opinions and things that people are sometimes super passionate about.